# Unit test works only on second run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am testing methods from one class and 7 methods in Unit class are executing fine, but 2 only work on second try.

When I run them, compiler say that test execution is complete 9/9, but 2 of them aren't executed, I have blue sigh beside those tests, like one u get when u rebuild project and don't run any of them.

On second run they work fine.

What is problem?

Comment: If there are 9 tests and you are being told that 9/9 tests are complete it might just be that Visual Studio is being slow to respond, I sometimes find this happens but if I open and close the test file and wait a second or two I eventually see the green tick

Comment: @mark_h I transferred to using NUnit application, there everything was smooth, only problem was that I can't debug.

Comment: Have you got the NUnit test adapter Nuget package installed? I don't think Visual Studio will see NUnit tests by default, you'd need the test adapter. You should then be able to run the unit tests inside visual studio and be able to debug them

Comment: @mark_h Probably don't, I'm not sure, I only referenced DLL from NUnit to my project and then used attributes for NUnit. But I'm done now.

Answer (score 2):

You should download the latest NUnit framework package.
Go to Tools->NuGet Package Manager-> Manage NuGet Packages-> Browse-> Search for NUnit unit-testing framework for .net.
That should fix the problem with the 2 passing test.